# Performs logout when user remove app via task swipe in android

Tags: android, android-service, swipe, logout

I want to clear user credentials and log user out when the user user removes the app from current running app list. Here, what I'm doing,  is that when user ends the app by swiping off the app list, the app within should perform a logout. But when user removes the app via swipe,  it does nothing. Below is my code.

```
public class MyService extends Service{

    public void onTaskRemoved(){
        Log.i("RootActivity:onTaskRemoved()","******TaskRemoved******");
        SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.pref_current_user), MODE_PRIVATE);             
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.clear();     // CLEAR ALL FILEDS
        editor.commit();    // COMMIT CHANGES
        Log.i("RootActivity:onTaskRemoved()","******APP LOGGEDOUT******");
        setloginButton();   // Change logout button to login
        Log.i("RootActivity:onTaskRemoved()","******loginButton is set******");
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your method `onTaskRemoved()` getting called ?

Comment: @VedPrakash nupp, it is not logged in the logcat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is that you only bound the service with `bindService()` and so `onTaskRemoved()` never get called.

Using Service you can -

- *Bind*
- *Start*
- *Bind and Start*

This [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) generally discusses these two types of services separately, your service can work both ways and that is what you need to do —

It can be started (`to run indefinitely`) and also allow binding.

It's simply a matter of whether you implement a couple callback methods: `onStartCommand()` to allow components to start it and `onBind()` to allow binding.

**To do both** -

```
startService(new Intent(context, MyService.class));

// Bind to the service
bindService(new Intent(context, MyService.class),
mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void onDestroy() {
SharedPreferences pref=getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.pref_current_user),MODE_PRIVATE);             
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
    editor.clear();     // CLEAR ALL FILEDS
    editor.commit();    // COMMIT CHANGES
    Log.i("RootActivity:onTaskRemoved()","******APP LOGGEDOUT******");
    setloginButton();   // Change logout button to login
    Log.i("RootActivity:onTaskRemoved()","******loginButton is set******");  
super.onDestroy();
}
```

add this in your activities....

Comment: This is not the method that I am looking at, because, in onDestroy method. It is unreliable, in the sense that it may not be call all the time, unless there is an instance of low memory within the device, then onDestroy will be called. But, thanks

Comment: I tested it on nexus 5 device, when i removed the app from current running app list, onDestroy was called. You wanted that only right ???

Comment: yes, onDestroy is called when you remove from the running app list, but the behaviour is erratic, inconsistent. The logout method is not called on a consistent basis; based on my assumption and understanding(it is called only when the device is low on memory and needs to clear some instances). Hence, i understand that it is not advisable to use onDestroy though, it is a good and simple method. I have tested that function on an Android -compatible device as well.

Answer (score 0):

When coupled with Firebase, it's as easy as

```
   @Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
}
```